# Frequency of precipitation above 95th percentile

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, suffix-array

so I have gridded precipitation data with dimenstion (324,72,144) being time, lon, lat respectively. I want to count count the frequeny of this data that is above the 95th percentile but I am really confused since this data is gridded. I would be glad for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the 95th percentile from? It doesn't make that much sense to ask "what percent of this data is above the 95th percentile, *within the same data*", because the answer to that will always be 5% by definition.

If you want to find the fraction of an array `X` that is above a certain value `c`, you can just write

```
(X>c).mean()
```